# Как выкачать 6 гб данных с сервера?

Tags: файлы, ssh

Есть ли специальный скрипт или утилита для выкачки данных с сервера архивом, поделенным на несколько частей небольшого объема?
Из исходных данных доступ к серверу по ssh

p.s Объем который надо скачать,больше 6 гб

Comment: Доступы были предоставлены со стороны,на сервере имеются ограничения по времени подключения,и долго выкачивать один крупный файл не получается.</br>
Выход из ситуации несколько маленьких архивов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну думаю как-то так:

```
tar -cz <папка> | split -b <размер>m <имя архива>

Это должно создать файлы вида 
<имя архива>aa 
<имя архива>ab 
<имя архива>ac
```

Просто надо понимать почему именно маленькими объемами. Имеете SSH значит есть SFTP взяли и скачали

Answer (score 1):

Лучше использовать rsync. В случае обрыва связи, вы смоэете продолжить скачивание с последнего места. Помимо этого в нем есть компрессия

Например: rsync -cavzP user@server://from /where_to_copy